# How to dynamically add lables for every name in MYSQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MYSQL database and I am trying to get the first name and last name of every student I put in the database and dynamically show them as a label in my WPF form, here is what I got so far

```
string connstr = "Server=localhost; Database=login; UID=root; Pwd=password";
MySqlConnection connc = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
MySqlCommand command;
connc.Open();

// Label[] labels = new Label[n];

try
{
     command = connc.CreateCommand();
     command.CommandText = "SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM Students";
     command.ExecuteReader();
     MessageBox.Show("S");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("something went wrong: " + ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
     connc.Close();
}
```

So how could I add all my entry's in the database to a label?

Answer (score 3):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method just executes your query. You can't get your values with it.

You need to use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at least to get your values. You can read your column values in a *while statement* with `MySqlDataReader.Read()` method. This method reads your query *row by row*.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader`.

```
using(MySqlConnection connc = new MySqlConnection(connstr))
using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM Students", connc))
{
   using(MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
           // reader[0] gets you first column which is First_name
           // reader[1] gets you second column which is Last_name
           // Do your label assingments..
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @user3487107 Updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

First , ExecuteNonQuery() method is used for DML statements INSERT ,UPDATE , DELETE .

Use ExecuteReader() method.

```
        command = connc.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM Students";

        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();  
        string result=string.Empty;              
        while(dr.Read())
        {
         result += dr["First_name"].ToString() + " " + dr["Last_name"].ToString(); 
        }

         lableId.Content=result;
```